# Solving a recuurence relation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

How can I solve the following recurrence relation?

> $f(n+1)=f(n)+f(n-1)+f(n-2), \ f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=1.$

I can use the characteristic equation which is $x^3=x^2+x+1$. It has three distinct roots $s,t,r$ therefore the general solution is $f(n)=as^n+bt^n+cr^n.$

Comment: Now put $n=0,1,2$ in that formula and solve for $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost done. All that remains is to find $a,b,c$.

Use the initial conditions to get a linear system for $a,b,c$.

You probably won't get nice numbers, because $s,t,r$ are not very nice (see [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+x3%3Dx2%2Bx%2B1)).

On the other hand, the matrix in the linear system is a [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) and its inverse can be computed [explicitly](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde%27s_Matrix).

Answer (score 1):

You essentially mentioned the answer in your question. We can find the characteristic polynomial for the recurrence relation by substituting $f(n) = x^n$ into the relation. This gives $x^{n+1} = x^n + x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}$ and after dividing out by $x^{n-2}$ ($x\neq 0$ by the initial conditions), we get $x^3-x^2-x-1=0$, which has three distinct roots $r,s,t$ (not integers). The general form is $f(n) = as^n + bt^n+cr^n$.

The initial conditions substituted into the equation gives $a+b+c=1, as+bt+cr = 1, as^2+bt^2+cr^2=1$, which can be solved to find $a,b,c$ uniquely.

Comment: uniquely *if* the roots are all different (which they are).

Comment: If any of the roots were repeated then the general form I wrote wouldn't be the full solution. A repeated (double) root $r$ say would need $ar^n+bnr^n$ added to the equation.

Comment: Yes, of course.